# How do I configure my AWS instance to serve a remote desktop so I can use Windows terminal services to access it?

Tags: xubuntu, aws, rdp

My evil plan is to serve rdp from an AWS ubuntu instance so I can have a permanent xubuntu desktop as I roam from windows computer to windows computer (or any computer really). It is as easy as running mstsc -v {aws.public.url}.

How, through, ssh, can I have the instance serve a remote desktop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: This answer is now outdated:

- xrdp no longer needs tightvnc for 11.04.. maybe 10.10 too

  - so, no need to install tightvnc, just install xrpd
  - so, also, the restriction on 64bit machines is lifted

Thanks to [nealmcb's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13232/how-do-i-configure-my-aws-instance-to-serve-a-remote-desktop-so-i-can-use-windows/13520#13520) and following the tightvnc + xrdp discussion, I've got it working here is my complete list of tasks to set up an mstsc -v able aws:

**Xubuntu not Ubuntu Desktop**

I originally tried an ubuntu desktop, but with a micro instance, the gui performance was too slow, switching to xubuntu gives a reasonably responsive remote desktop

**AWS Setup**

1. Create a Key Pair (save as a .pem file to local machine)
2. Modify Default Security Group, add RDP, tcp, 3389, 3389, 0.0.0.0/0
3. Create AWS instance: Canonical ami-508c7839

   - (i386 important due to 64 bug in tightvnc)
   - use this for the user data section

`#cloud-config`

```
apt_update: true
apt_upgrade: true
packages:
 - xubuntu-desktop
 - indicator-applet-session
 - gnome-themes-selected
 - tightvncserver
 - xrdp
```

**SSH access on windows**

1. download putty and puttygen
2. with puttygen: create a .ppk from the .pem
3. putty {awc.public.url}, ssh auth with .ppk file

**Server Setup**

You might have to wait for the xubuntu-desktop apt-get to finish before the xrdp.ini is available.

```
sudo vim /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
# remove the entries below the xrdp1 block
sudo adduser me
sudo addgroup me admin
```

now I can mstsc -v {aws.public.url} into the aws.

**D Keystroke Problem**

- System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts
- Change Show Desktop Shortcut from D to alt-D

Thanks to the following resources:

AWS Install Guide

http://foss-boss.blogspot.com/2010/10/pointnclick-guide-to-running-ubuntu-in.html

Xubuntu AWS Install Guide

http://blog.topicbranch.net/2010/08/xubuntu-and-neatx-on-ec2.html

TightVNC+XRDP

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1077607

TightVNC 1.3.9 64bit Issues

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/344264/

RDP D key Problem

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1595871

Fast Switch Applet Problem

http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1365262

Comment: Thanks for documenting your process - that's a huge help and a good guide to others trying to do the same thing! :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about running an rds-compatible service, but if you can't find one, VNC should meet your needs - just install a VNC server on AWS, and a VNC client on the windows machines.  See e.g. [this VNC discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7113/vnc-setup-over-ssh)