# How to launch the GUI only sometimes on Ubuntu 12.04 server?

Tags: server, desktop-environments

I just installed Ubuntu server 12.04 and would like a GUI based interface, but only when I need it.  I want to be able to launch the desktop when I'm trying to configure stuff (and can't use the command line), then reboot and not have it appear unless I tell it too to reduce the required resources during normal server operation.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: When you say, "can't use the command line", you mean when you are not able to login in a shell? Or you login in the shell then fire up the desktop?

Comment: im saying in instances where I have to use a graphical interface in say firefox to configure my raid controller and such.  So just want to have access to the desktop environment but not have it running all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is for a light desktop that you can start whenever you want (based in your comments) and that you can stop when you are done. For that before it was recommended gnome, but now the way to go is lxde or xfce. Is up to you what to install:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install lxde-core xorg-core // If you want lxde
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install xfce4 xorg-core // If you want xfce
```

From there on, you should be able to use the `startx` command to fire up a Xserver session.

### For a headless server

For a headless server the procedure is almost the same, just that you might have to use SSH+VNC tunneling if the server is a remote location. There was already a question that was answered (several times) about how to do so, so I won't repeat the same again: https://askubuntu.com/a/7167/169736

Comment: It will not automatically restart when I reboot the system?  Can I put firefox on it? (for the top suggestion)

Comment: When you restart, it will not start when you boot up. And yeah, you can install any application and you will get it.