# VNC Connection w/ SSH tunneling

Tags: ssh, vnc, remmina

I want to VNC connect to an Ubuntu 20.04 desktop from an Ubuntu 22.04 desktop (both in same LAN). I've tried  [Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7113/vnc-setup-over-ssh)
and it seemed like I was able to SSH into the remote machine and start x11vnc but I was unable to connect with Remmina.
I think I have some settings wrong

I'm using [these basic settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H58dz.png) and [no SSH tunneling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tekfa.png) because I believe the port is already forwarded to my local machine?

After a few seconds of saying it's connecting I just see a black screen. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Edit: I edited `/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service` like in this [top answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen) and tried again without SSH tunnel and that worked.

There's a bit of input delay though (~1 second or so). Since this is over LAN I figured it would be a bit more responsive. Is there something I can do about that?

Edit #2: Actually it worked once and not anymore. When I disconnected the VNC (client side) an error messaged showed up (server side) that says `System program problem detected` and this message shows up every two minutes or so. On the client side it seems like I can connect, at least it doesn't throw any obvious error message. But the screen is all black (still with no SSH tunneling)

Comment: Does VNC work if you don't use the `ssh` tunnel and VNC directly into the IP address of your Ubuntu 20.04 desktop? First, rule out the problem is at the VNC or at the ssh tunnel. [Update your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1432623/edit) and add information about running VNC without ssh first. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen) for how to setup x11VNC in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206883/how-to-prevent-x11vnc-attacks-attempts-to-unauthorized-logins/1206977#1206977) for how to setup Remmina for VNC with SSH tunnel.